# Drawing lines between values on plot in R

Tags: r, graph, plot

I have a dataframe "df" that has 120 rows and 2 columns containing numbers as shown...

```
    V1    V2
    10001    177417
    227418    267719  
    317720    471368
```

I want to be able to lay these along the X-axis of a plot with a line connecting the values from V1 t0 V2 in each row.

one option would be to use `seq(V1,V2)` for each row then concatenate to create a full series, However with the the amount of data involved, the object size runs to >10GB and is therefore not a viable option. The Y-axis position here is not important.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a plot object, then enter the rest of the rows using the `segments` function:

```
plot(x=c(1,1), y=df[1,], xlim = c(1,nrow(df)), ylim=range(df), type='l')
segments(x0=2:nrow(df), x1=2:nrow(df), y0=df[-1,1], y1=df[-1,2])
```

Here is how it looks on a random cumulative set:

```
df <- apply(as.data.frame(cbind(rnorm(1000),rnorm(1000))),2,cumsum)
```

[image]

Comment: seqments is vectorized, you don't need a loop

Comment: `segments(1:3,df[,1],1:3,df[,2])` does the same

Comment: Thanks segments is exactly what i was looking for. to simplfy i just needed this `segments(x0=df$V1, x1=df$V2, y0=1, y1=1)`